# Conditional Calculation of Pandas Dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have a pandas dataframe which reads

```
Category  Sales  
A           10
B           20
```

I wanna do a conditional creation of new column target

And I want my target df to look like

```
Category  Sales  Target 
A           10    5
B           20   10
```

I used the below code and it threw an error

```
if(df['Category']=='A'):
    df['Target']=df['Sales']-5
else:
    df['Target']=df['Sales']-10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use vectorized [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Target']= np.where(df['Category']=='A', df['Sales'] - 5, df['Sales'] - 10)
print (df)
  Category  Sales  Target
0        A     10       5
1        B     20      10
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael , actually I tried the same approach. But somehow I messed up with the syntax. Again thanks for helping out