# Conditional creation of a Dataframe column, where the calculation of the column values change based on row input

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a very long and wide dataframe. I'd like to create a new column in that dataframe, where the value depends on many other columns in the df. The calculation needed for the values in this new column, ALSO change, depending on a value in some other column.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483428/conditional-calculation-of-pandas-dataframe-columns) come close, but don't quite work out for me.

I'll eventually have about 30 different calculations that could be applied, so I'm not too keen on the `np.where` function, which is not that readible for too many conditions.

I've also been strongly adviced against doing a for-loop over all rows in a dataframe, because it's supposed to be awful for performance (please correct me if I'm wrong there).

What I've tried to do instead:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Information in my columns look something like this:
df['text'] = ['dab', 'def', 'bla', 'zdag', 'etc']
df['values1'] = [3 , 4, 2, 5, 2]
df['values2'] = [6, 3, 21, 44, 22]
df['values3'] = [103, 444, 33, 425, 200]

# lists to check against to decide upon which calculation is required
someList = ['dab', 'bla']
someOtherList = ['def', 'zdag']
someThirdList = ['etc']

conditions = [
    (df['text'] is None),
    (df['text'] in someList),
    (df['text'] in someOtherList),
    (df['text'] in someThirdList)]
choices = [0, 
           round(df['values2'] * 0.5 * df['values3'], 2), 
           df['values1'] + df['values2'] - df['values3'], 
           df['values1'] + 249]
df['mynewvalue'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
print(df)
```

I expect that based on the row values in the `df['text']`, the right calculation is applied to same row value of `df['mynewvalue']`.

Instead, I get the error `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

How can I program this instead, so that I can use these kind of conditions to define the right calculation for this df['mynewvalue'] column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors come from the conditions:

```
conditions = [
    ... ,
    (df['text'] in someList),
    (df['text'] in someOtherList),
    (df['text'] in someThirdList)]
```

You try to ask if several elements are in a list. The answer is a list (for each element). As the error suggests, you have to decide if the condition is verified when at least one element verify the property (`any`) or if all the elements verify the property (`any`).

One solution is to use `isin` [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) or `all` [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for `pandas` dataframes.

Here using `any`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Information in my columns look something like this:
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['text'] = ['dab', 'def', 'bla', 'zdag', 'etc']
df['values1'] = [3, 4, 2, 5, 2]
df['values2'] = [6, 3, 21, 44, 22]
df['values3'] = [103, 444, 33, 425, 200]

# other lists to test against whether
someList = ['dab', 'bla']
someOtherList = ['def', 'zdag']
someThirdList = ['etc']

conditions = [
    (df['text'] is None),
    (df['text'].isin(someList)),
    (df['text'].isin(someOtherList)),
    (df['text'].isin(someThirdList))]
choices = [0,
           round(df['values2'] * 0.5 * df['values3'], 2),
           df['values1'] + df['values2'] - df['values3'],
           df['values1'] + 249]
df['mynewvalue'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
print(df)
#    text  values1  values2  values3  mynewvalue
# 0   dab        3        6      103       309.0
# 1   def        4        3      444      -437.0
# 2   bla        2       21       33       346.5
# 3  zdag        5       44      425      -376.0
# 4   etc        2       22      200       251.0
```

Comment: You've made my day! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help you ! Feel free to accept the answer if that solve your problem :-)